# Dates seemingly available according to Airbnb calendar show: "Those dates are not available"

Tags: airbnb

I was attempting to book an [Airbnb apartment](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/20755787?guests=1&adults=1&location=Copenhagen%2C%20Denmark&check_in=2017-09-06&check_out=2017-09-11&s=kLWI5IjM) from  2017-09-06 to  2017-09-11, which seemed to be available according to the calendar:

[image: Calendar]

and the map:

[image: Map]

However, it said "Those dates are not available"

[image: Message]

Why?